# Integration with google drive in apex

Tags: apex, visualforce, integration, google-drive

how to integrate google drive from vfPage. like when we upload any file like image/text/pdf/doc/excel etc. save into google drive.and retrieve from google drive its show there hyperlink , when click on the hyperlink it will open.

any example is highly appreciable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we need to integrate salesforce with google drive, then you can upload files from vf page to google drive.
Please see below link how to integrate with google drive
https://theforcetimes.wordpress.com/2012/12/15/integration-of-google-drive-into-force-com/

http://forceguru.blogspot.ae/2014/05/google-drive-authentication-in.html